# How to split on "^A" character

Tags: java, string, split

I have a raw txt file that I would like to perform a split operation on.

When I view the data in vim the line appears as follows:

```
col1^Acol2^Acol3^Acol4
```

When I try and split the line using `^A` as my split function it does not split on this character.

Comment: yourString.split("A\^");

Comment: @JREN that does not compile in Java, and he said ^A, not the other way around.

Comment: woops :p my bad sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In vi(m) `^A` or Ctrl-A is  `\u0001`.

```
String[] words = line.split("\u0001");
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape `^`, or include it in a character class. It has special meaning in regex.
Preferable, I'm not a big fan of escaping. So I try to avoid it as much as I can in Regex. So, here I'll use character class. So just split on:

```
[^]A
```

You can also escape the `^`:

```
\\^A
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [public static String quote(String s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns a **literal pattern String** for the specified String

```
myString.split(Pattern.quote("^A"));
```

Because `^` is a special character, and [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) accepts a *regex*.

Comment: He want to split with ^A, not only ^

Answer (score 1):

In vi(m) ^A or Ctrl-A is  \u0001.

String[] words = line.split("\\u0001");

Comment: you should escape \